# Create or update function of realm framework not working in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, realm

I am using the Realm framework for iOS and I'm trying to create multiple objects in an array from a parse query, but keeping in check that there are none that are repeated in the local realm.

```
let lastSyncDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("com.fridge.sync.last") as NSDate
let query = PFQuery(className: "Category", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "updatedAt > %@", lastSyncDate))
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
    return
  }
  if results.isEmpty {
    return
  }
  let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
  /*realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
    for remoteCategory in results as [PFObject] {
      let category = Category()
      category.name = remoteCategory["name"] as String
      category.image = NSData()
      realm.addObject(category)
    }
  })*/
  /*realm.beginWriteTransaction()
  for remoteCategory in results as [PFObject] {
    let category = Category()
    category.name = remoteCategory["name"] as String
    category.image = NSData()
    realm.addObject(category)
  }
  realm.commitWriteTransaction()*/
}
```

I also used the creatorupdate version but it still doesn't save any of the objects and for some reason I can't debug anything of what is heppening inside of the realm code.

The category model is like this:

```
class Category: RLMObject {
  dynamic var categoryId: String = ""
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var image: NSData = NSData()
  var stores: [Store] {
    return linkingObjectsOfClass(Store.className(), forProperty: "category") as [Store]
  }

  override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "categoryId"
  }
}
```

Any idea of what could possibly be going wrong is greatly appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are setting the `categoryID` property on your objects. This would cause all of them to use the same primary key and overwrite the same object when using `createOrUpdate`

To debug and step into the Realm code you will probably need to build from source.

Comment: Ok it worked as you mentioned, thanks a lot. What did you mean by building from source?

Comment: Realm is open source and if you build the framework yourself then you can debug the Realm code more easily. Realm's source is available here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa